# SAP Hybris Commerce 6.2 Cuppy Project Setup Issues

Tags: java, spring, polymorphism, sap-commerce-cloud, erasure

Name clash: The method `convertAll(Collection<SOURCE>)` of type GenericCollectionConverter has the same erasure as `convertAll(Collection<? extends SOURCE>)` of type Converter but does not override it
Below files giving the error above while doing Ant Clean All installation in CMD, using Java 1.8 and WS-Core 2.3 jar

```
    package de.hybris.platform.cuppy.web.converters;

    import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.dto.converter.GenericConverter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.List;


    /**
     * @author andreas.thaler
     * 
     */
    public class GenericCollectionConverter<SOURCE, TARGET> extends GenericConverter<SOURCE, TARGET> implements
            CollectionConverter<SOURCE, TARGET>
    {

        @Override
        public List<TARGET> convertAll(Collection<SOURCE> sources)
        {
            // YTODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    }



    /**
     * 
     */
    package de.hybris.platform.cuppy.web.converters;

    import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.dto.converter.Converter;

    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;


    /**
     * @author andreas.thaler
     * 
     */
    public interface CollectionConverter<SOURCE, TARGET> extends Converter<SOURCE, TARGET>
    {
        /**
         * Converts all sources to new instances of target type.
         */
        List<TARGET> convertAll(final Collection<SOURCE> sources);
    }
```